# a brief grapple with a lady of the night

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Surprisingly, he finds he will leave Dover richer than he arrived.
>   He'd watched a man doing the three-card trick, and when he learned it
>   he set up for himself. Because he's a boy, people stop to have a go.
>   It's their loss. He adds up what he's got and what he's spent.
>   **Deduct a small sum for a brief grapple with a lady of the night.** Not the sort of thing you could do in Putney, Wimbledon or Mortlake.
>   Not without the Williams family getting to know, and talking about you
>   in Welsh.

(Wolf Hall by Hilary Mantel)

What does "**a brief grapple with a lady of the night**" mean? It sounds like buying sex.

Comment: That's exactly what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `lady of the night` is indeed a prostitute. Having a `brief grapple` is having sex. `deduct a small sum` is saying that the prostitute's fee was small, at least compared to the rest of his money.

I will say that I would consider a `brief grapple` to be an uncommon and not obvious way to phrase it, so your uncertainty is quite understandable.

You will find, however, that `lady of the night` is a fairly common name for a prostitute.